# D3 Parsing error for multi-line plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know this has been asked before but I've been trying to debug this for a while now.

I'm trying to plot multiple lines, but for now, I'm just testing just one line of data.

http://jsfiddle.net/csebranek/3yH75/3/

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,450LNaN,444.1011235955056CNaN, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the original `data` to the function that sets the domain for your x scale, but the parsed dates are in `lakes`. As this is a nested structure, you can't use the same code for extracting the extreme values, but code along the same lines as the one used to set the domain of the y scale:

```
x.domain([
  d3.min(lakes, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.date; }); }),
  d3.max(lakes, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.date; }); })
]);
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3yH75/4/).

Answer (score 0):

This is the output when your `x` scale, applied to your data, returns `NaN` (i.e. any non-numeric value).

In this case, it looks like your line generator is looking for `x(d.date);` but you're parsing the dates as `d.LocalDateTime`. So it's calling `x(undefined)`.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but `LocalDateTime` is actually stored in `date` in the structure that's eventually passed to `.data()`. The problem is that the domain of the x scale isn't set up properly.